# How to make field in abstract class common in inner classes without making static?

Tags: java, class, static, abstract-class, software-design

Suppose I have the following abstract class with nested static classes:

```java
/**
 * Command class.
 */
public abstract class Command {
    public String commandName; // The name of the command.

    private Command() {}

    /**
     * Help command.
     */
    public static final class Help extends Command {
        public Help() { this.commandName = "help"; }
    }

    /**
     * Selection command.
     */
    public static final class Select extends Command {
        public final int choice;
        public Select(int choice) {
            this.commandName = "select";
            this.choice = choice;
        }
    }
}
```

I want the ability to access the field `commandName` from the `Help` and `Select` classes through `Command.Help.commandName`, for example. Unfortunately I can't seem to do this because the commandName field is not static. Let's say I "fix" this issue by making `commandName` static. The next problem arises when I run the following block of code:

```java
Command c1 = new Command.Help();
System.out.println(Command.Help.commandName);
Command c2 = new Command.Select();
System.out.println(Command.Help.commandName);
```

This block outputs

```
help
select
```

when I would have expected

```
help
help
```

because I want the respective command names for `Help` and `Select` to stay fixed no matter what instances of either command I instantiate. Is the only solution to create a `commandName` field for every class, or is there a less repetitive way to do this?

Comment: why not pass the command name to the super class via the constructor?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use `Command.Help.commandName`. You have access to the `commandName` field of the superclass instance within `Help` and `Command`.

Comment: @tgdavies can you further elaborate on this? I want to use `Command.Help.commandName` because I don't want to initialise instances of either command classes just to check if the string representation of a command name matches with a command in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **shadow** the `commandName` field

```java
/**
 * Command class.
 */
public abstract class Command {
    public String commandName; // The name of the command.

    private Command() {}

    /**
     * Help command.
     */
    public static final class Help extends Command {
        public static final String commandName = "help"; // Command.Help.commandName will reach this
        public Help() {  }
    }

    /**
     * Selection command.
     */
    public static final class Select extends Command {
        public static final String commandName = "select"; // Command.Select.commandName will reach this

        public final int choice;
        public Select(int choice) {
            this.choice = choice;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the command name via the super's constructor.

```
abstract class Command {
    public String commandName; 

    protected Command(String name) {
       this.commandName = name;
    }
    
    public String getName(){
       return commandName;
    }
    
    public static final class Help extends Command {
        public Help() { super("help"); }
    }

    public static final class Select extends Command {
        public final int choice;
        public Select(int choice) {
            super("select");
            this.choice = choice;
        }
    }
}
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Command c1 = new Command.Help();
      System.out.println(c1.getName());
      Command c2 = new Command.Select(2);
      System.out.println(c2.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution for a different problem because I can't access `commandName` statically.

Comment: In that case, what's wrong with using the class name directly?

Comment: I don't want to make instances of either class just so I can check if the string representation of a command eg: "help" is equal to the `commandName` of one of the command classes.